# Google Chrome: All images on all sites are being rendered improperly, corrupted

Tags: google-chrome

This is my bug report on Chromium project: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=128703

```
Chrome Version       : 19.0.1084.46
OS Version: 6.1 (Windows 7 64-bit)
```

URLs (if applicable) : http://cs5847.userapi.com/u21361918/docs/2b059b32a323/TEST_SHOT.jpg

Other browsers tested:

Add OK or FAIL after other browsers where you have tested this issue:

```
Safari 5: OK
Firefox 12: OK
IE 7/8/9: OK/OK/OK
```

What steps will reproduce the problem?

```
1. Open specified image in Google Chrome.
```

What is the expected result?

```
Text on image must be shown clean, without any corruptions.
```

What happens instead?

```
Text on image is shown with some corruptions on sides, contours.
```

This problem is illustrated on additional streenshots. Test image itself is attached too. JPG quality of all images is 100%. If you are using Chrome 19.0.1084.46, better download pictures and open in independent image viewer, otherwise you will see screenshots corrupted too. This problem is affecting ALL IMAGES on all sites. This particular image is just showing problem most clearly.

UserAgentString: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/536.5 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/19.0.1084.46 Safari/536.5

**Question:** is it only me? Is there anyone who experienced this too?
After posting report bug, nothing happenned so far. How much does it take to verify report bug on code.google.com/p/chromium/?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<strike>What you see is JPG compression.</strike>

I'll post an example in a few minutes.

I'm wrong. Huh. This is interesting. I've tested JPGs with both an sRGB embedded profile, and no profile, but they both had the same problem. I'll run some more tests.

I think your issue is a duplicate of [issue #122951](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=122951).

Comment: If you open tested image in picture viewer or any other browser, or Chrome browser version 18, for example, you will see that there is no JPG compression (at least this big). JPG quality of this image is 100%

Comment: Yes, it seems that it`s really a duplicate of issue you specified. Thanks. Will hope they`ll fix it next release.